# Right way to choose and instantiate C# class depends on string value?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dynamic-programming

I have base class

```
public abstract class HostBehavior : SiteHost
{
    public abstract List<string> ParseNews(string url);
}
```

And many derived classes...

What is the best way to choose which constructor should be called depends on url?

Right now I have long sequence of "if else" statements like this example:

```
public static HostBehavior ResolveHost(string url)
{
    if (uri.IndexOf("stackoverflow.com") > 0)
    {
        return new stackoverflowBehavior();
    }
    else if(uri.IndexOf("google.com") > 0)
    {
        return new googleBehavior();
    }
    // and so on...
    else
    {
        throw new Exception...
    }
}
```

Comment: How performant does this need to be? Is the overhead associated with reflection fine?

Comment: Probably fine. Performance in my case not on first place, ease of support more important.

Comment: In that case, you could do it with a Map then instantiate the class with reflection. In .NET, I believe the equivalent class is `Dictionary<string, Class>`.

Comment: Static `Dictionary<string, Func<HostBehavior>>`, get the domain from `Uri.Host`. No need for reflection. OTOH you can save some boilerplate coding with `Dictionary<string, Func<Type>>`, and creating the instances with `Assembly.CreateInstance()` rather than a lambda.

Comment: Thanks for replies, I'm not familiar with this language features, I'll look closely on it.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to give each class a custom [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class | System.AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class HostAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string name;

    public HostAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So my classes looks like

```
[Host("stackoverflow.com")]
public class stackoverflowBehavior : HostBehavior
{
//...
}
```

Now I can get all classes from assembly's folder|namespace

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type[] hostTypes = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(a => a.IsClass && a.Namespace != null && a.Namespace.Contains(@"Hosts"))
            .ToArray();
```

Finally I need to find type with HostAttribute same as incoming url.Host

```
foreach(Type t in hostTypes)
{
     HostAttribute attribute = (HostAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(HostAttribute));
     if (attribute.name ==  url.Host)
         return (HostBehavior)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```

I want to thank everyone quotes, especially to Ed Plunkett.

Answer (score 0):

looking at scenario you explained in your query, it seems you can use factory pattern to accommodate your requirements.